# How do I access a Class in Java in my main class

Tags: java, class, methods

How do I access my "Cone" class from my "Main" class. The error I am getting is the dot operator in my Main class. I'm really new to java so Im really confused as to how you access what I have created in the "Cone" class any details would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

```
class Cone {

    public double r;
    public double h;

    public void setRadius() {
        r = r;
    }

    public void setHeight() {
        h = h;
    }

    public double volume(double r, double h) {
        double v;
        v = Math.PI * Math.pow(r, 2) * (h / 3);
        return v;
    }

    public double surfaceArea(double r, double h) {
        double sa;
        sa = Math.PI * r * (r + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(h, 2) + Math.pow(r, 2)));
        return sa;
    }

}

class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        double r;
        double h;

        Cone cone = new Cone();

        for (double i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            cone.volume(r);
            cone.volume(h);

            System.out.printf("Volume =  %d\n", cone.Volume());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick fix for you

```
class Cone 
{
public double r;
public double h;

public void setRadius(double r)
{
    this.r = r;

}

public void setHeight(double h)
{
    this.h = h;

}

public double volume()
{
    double v;

    v = Math.PI * Math.pow(r,2) * (h/3);
    return v;
}

public double surfaceArea()
{
    double sa;

    sa = Math.PI* r * (r + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(h,2) + Math.pow(r,2)));

    return sa;
}
```

}

```
class Main
{

 public static void main(String args[ ])
 {
    double r;
    double h;

    Cone cone = new Cone();

    for (double i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
               // r and h are not set yet
               r = h = i;  // maybe?
               cone.setRadius(r);
               cone.setHeight(h);

               System.out.printf("Volume =  %d\n", cone.volume( ));
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much this makes sense now

Comment: @juanmindset A quick edit I have made is to actually set r and h to some value before using.

Comment: Yeah now im getting an error with the cone.volume()

Comment: now im getting this  
Volume =  Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.Double
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printInteger(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.PrintStream.format(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.PrintStream.printf(Unknown Source)
        at Main.main(Main.java:17)

Comment: Yes %d is for printing an int.  A double will be %f, so try  `System.out.printf("Volume =  %f\n", cone.volume( ));`

Comment: Duhhh -_- sorry im a noob that you so much it worked! Now i just have to make the surface area one

Answer (score 0):

I think your mistake is that `cone.Volume()` should be `cone.volume()`. And also, you need to provide parameters. I would modify the Cone class by getting rid of those set methods and adding a parameterized constructor like so:

```
public Cone(double r, double h)
{
  //initialize fields
  this.r = r;
  this.h = h
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first error update you code

```
 public void setRadius(double r)
    {
        this.r = r;

    }

    public void setHeight(double h)
    {
        this.h = h;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the values by `setter`, but in your code the setter for the variables don't have any parameter to accept:

```
public void setRadius(double r) {
    this.r = r;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, you would probably want a constructor that can initialize the dimensions

```
public Cone(double r, double h){
    this.r = r;
    this.h = h;
}
```

Next, your `volume` method expects two double arguments

```
//use this
cone.volume(r,h);
//not this
cone.volume(r);
cone.volume(h);
```

Finally, since this method returns a double with the volume, you will want to have another double variable to catch it for later use

```
double v = cone.volume(r,h);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Declare your Main class as public. (Suggestion)
2. cone.volume() requires 2 parameters. You can not append 2 parameters one after another. Instead of cone.volume(r); cone.volume(h); You need to pass r and h in single statement like : cone.volume(r,h); Because you have mentioned original volume(par1, par2). Assign some value to r and h either by setter or by using constructor.

For a basic start hardcode some values to r and h in Main class only.